# Angular $resource custom method

Tags: angularjs

I've followed the examples but apparently something is wrong when adding a custom method to the resource's prototype.

```
app.factory('Product',function ($resource,$cacheFactory) {
        var Product = $resource('/the/url/:id', {id: '@id'}),
            cache = $cacheFactory('Product'),
            products;
        Product.prototype.all = function(){
            products = cache.get('all');
            if(typeof products == 'undefined'){
                products = Product.query();
                cache.put('all',products);
            }
            return products;
        };
        return Product;
    })
```

In the controller I do `$scope.products = Product.all();` but I get

```
TypeError: Object function Resource(value) {
    copy(value || {}, this);
} has no method 'all'
```

Comment: Can you provide the link for the example of adding to the $resource's prototype? I don't remember ever seeing that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Product.prototype.all` defines an instance method.

You should define it as static method `Product.all = function(){...]`.

Only then you can call it with `$scope.products = Product.all();`.

Comment: Thanks, I dont know why at this point I make that kind of mistake XD

Comment: Understandable. These simple bugs often slip through easily in complex projects, or on long days.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because you don't actually have an instance yet. You would need to do this:

```
$scope.products = new Product();
// now you can run the all function
$scope.products.all()
```

Your other option would be to define the all() method on the service level. Instead of adding to the prototype, which is only available after new Product(), you could modify like:

```
app.factory('Product',function ($resource,$cacheFactory) {
    var Product = $resource('/the/url/:id', {id: '@id'}),
        cache = $cacheFactory('Product'),
        products;
    Product.all = function(){
        products = cache.get('all');
        if(typeof products == 'undefined'){
            products = Product.query();
            cache.put('all',products);
        }
        return products;
    };
    Product.prototype.$all = function () {
        Product.all.call(this);
    }
    return Product;
})
```

This way you will have Product.all() on the resource and product.$all() on instances.

Comment: When the resource is injected isn't it an instance of the defined service? How can I do this without instantiating the service?

Comment: When it's injected, you get an instance of the service, yes, but not an instance of a resource. Updating answer to include how you could call a service-level all() method.